# Relative position in Jade/Stylus not "taking"

Tags: css, meteor, pug, stylus

So, I have a stylus block that looks like this:

```
ul.nav.navbar-nav.li
    box-sizing border-box
    color #333
    position relative
    display block
    float left
    font-size 17px
    font-weight 300
    line-height 20.4px
    list-style-image none
    list-style-position outside
    list-style-type none
    visibility visible
```

When I deploy the test page to meteor and check the CSS properties of the li, the `position: relative` property just isn't there. What I mean:

[image: positioning not taking].

Is there any way to get stylus to use the relative positioning so my navbar will look right?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please have a look at the edits made to your question. There are some neat formatting tricks.

Comment: And there is no `position: relative` in the generated CSS file? Maybe you have a transparent mixin with name `position`?

Answer (score 0):

It's juste because your "position relative" property indentation is : 
 - Tab 
or 
 - Space

If all other property are tab, you should tab it, if they all are space you should space it, then, it will be compiled.